# Why should I not run setspn.exe on the domain controller?

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos, spn

I found several references (see below) on blogs that the setspn.exe utility should be run from either a client or server machine in the domain, but not from the domain controller itself.

http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-use-setspn-to-set-active-directory-service-principal-names-2.htm
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/20/configuring-kerberos-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx

What is the reason for this? What happens if I run setspn.exe on the domain controller anyway?
I'm asking because an SPN I set disappears after a little while.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure *why* they say, or said that, but I don't believe it's valid, at least not anymore, or not for the general case.

In fact, the [MSDN documentation for registering an SPN for SQL Server 2014 Report Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281382.aspx) explicitly directs you to login to a domain controller to run `setspn`.

Comment: Interesting, this conflicting information. Can't think of a reason why you would have to run the utility on the domain controller either. I would assume that no matter where you run the utility, the SPN gets registered in Active Directory.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly because of the real or imagined impact on DC performance:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2013/07/01/interesting-findings-on-setspn-x-f.aspx

... but I can't find a "this will bork AD" reason for the recommendation.